# Authorizing my website Google Sign In through a Webview

Tags: android, ios, facebook, webview, oauth-2.0

I have a website application that I have successfully integrated google and facebook signin. The problem is that if the site is linked to someone through a native app like Facebook Messenger, when the link is clicked, a Webview is created to present the website.  Google signin now prevents authorization through webviews and I cannot get the authorization to work. Facebook seems to corrupt the callback url adding a "cb=" to the end of the url.

I have looked into several workarounds:

- Have my website force a native browser to open
- app-claimed https redirection
- Deep linking

Nothing I seem to try or search has a solution for this.  I own the website and not the webview in this instance.  I have seen other websites authenticate this way through webviews and I cannot figure out how they are doing it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Google sign in you will need to use the AppAuth pattern to sign in, which is considered best mobile practice, and enforced by some providers.

This involves the mobile app itself opening a system 'in app' browser and triggering an OpenID Connect authorization request. You will not be able to use a website to perform the mobile sign in.

To get started with the AppAuth pattern, maybe start with my blog posts below, then see if you can reconfigure the samples to use Google configuration for the sign in:

- [Android AppAuth code sample](https://authguidance.com/2018/02/20/android-setup/)
- [iOS AppAuth code sample](https://authguidance.com/2018/02/20/ios-setup/)

Happy to answer follow up questions, but hopefully this gets you started in the right direction ...

Comment: I believe this solution means that I have to provide a mobile app?  I don't have a mobile app and don't intend to create one.  I have a website that users sometimes open on a phone.  Sometimes they get the link to open that via facebook or slack. This causes those apps to use their in app browser instead of opening the website in a native browser.  I hope I explained this well.  Thanks for the reply!

Comment: Ah - I see - there will be no problem it the website is opened properly in the mobile browser. Another similar problem is if you use 'Full Screen' home page shortcuts to run a web app as a mobile app - this also uses a web view. In both cases the Web UI is being misused, though this is hard to explain. Google logins will be blocked - though most other providers allow the login. At a previous company we ended up doing a mobile app to improve the Login UX - eg store tokens in the keychain so that the user doesn't have to login on every app restart.